# Is there a method to get a full windows build number in python?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I m struggling with the windows build number, i want to get it in full size, therefore decimal are included, I have only found this code:

```
version = sys.getwindowsversion()
print(version.build)
```

the output is:

```
19043
```

but i need to get the full length of the build number :C, how can I overcome this issue?

SOLUTION FOUNDED:

```
import os
os.system('ver')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1052]
```

ty everyone

Comment: Do you mean `'.'.join([str(x) for x in sys.getwindowsversion()])` or even `'.'.join([str(x) for x in sys.getwindowsversion() if x!=''])`?

Comment: as long as it works yes, I will try it out and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You got the acces to the rest of the build numbers via `version.major`, `version.minor`

```
sys.getwindowsversion(major=10, minor=0, build=19041, platform=2, service_pack='')
```

Alternatively you can use

```
import platform
platform.version()
platfotm.platform()
```

the output looks like :

```
'10.0.19041'
'Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0'
```

## EDIT

Its one more option. Run powershell script from python and catch the output. First thing to do is allow run powershell commands from outside : `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` run in PS Than use code like :

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
              "Get-ItemProperty -Path c:\windows\system32\hal.dll.VersionInfo.FileVersion"], 
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

the output should be like :
`10.0.19041.964 (WinBuild.160101.0800)`

Comment: unfortunately not, I need decimal point after '19041.etcetc'